# How to sort the annotations on the MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

How to sort the annotations (MKAnnotation) on the MKMapView ?

Comment: on what basis do you want to sort these annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting annotations on MKMapView I use didAddAnnotationViews callback:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
        for (MKAnnotationView * annView in views) {
        if ([annView.annotations isTop]) {
            [[annView superview] bringSubviewToFront:annView];
        } else {        
            [[annView superview] sendSubviewToBack:annView];
        }
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [mapView.annotations sortedArrayUsingComparator:<#^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)cmptr#>];
```

Basically mapView.annotations will give you an access to your all annotations in NSArray, and then use sortedArray...methods (`there are lots of different one`), which will help sorting your annotation array and return new sorted NSArry.

Hope this is what you are asking,

Cheers